# submit form with jQuery validation via smoke confirm

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I would like to submit my form - after a conformation window has been approved via the [smoke](http://smoke-js.com/docs/) option (bootstrap 2.0.3). this was working perfectly until I plugged the validation in, but now, even when you confirm - nothing happens. the form does not submit.

Here is my code, with a couple of options a tried.

you assitance is appreciated!

```
$("#enroller").validate({
            submitHandler: function() {
            //tried also: submitHandler: function(form) {

                var selectedCount = $(".gradeOption[value!='']").length;

                var questionAmount = selectedCount; // count how many fields were filled

                smoke.confirm('you are about to submit '+questionAmount+' grades - please confirm.',function(e){
                    if (e){
                        $("#enroller").submit();
                        //tried also: $(form).submit();
                    }else{
                        smoke.alert('save was cancelled', {ok:"close"});
                    }
                }, {ok:"yes - save", cancel:"cancel"});


            } //submitHandler

}); //validate
```

Comment: Show the rest of the code.  You don't call `validate()` more than once, do you?  What about the relevant HTML markup?  You have a valid `action` attribute within your `<form>` tag?  Any JavaScript console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `submitHandler` callback function, you then must program some kind of `submit` back into it, either via `ajax` or the default `form` `action`.

Within the appropriate location of your `submitHandler` logic, put a `$(form).submit();` which will immediately trigger submission of the default `form` `action`.

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // <- pass in the "form" argument
    // your other code
    $(form).submit();  // <- trigger default form action
}
```

**NOTE**:

- To use `$(form).submit();`, you must pass the `form` argument into the function.
- You must have a valid `action` attribute within your `<form>` tag.

As you can see, it's working:  http://jsfiddle.net/wD2Qn/

---

I noticed the following syntax error in your code.  You have a brace, `}`, that would prematurely close the `submitHandler` function, thus breaking the jQuery Validate plugin.

```
submitHandler: function() {

    var selectedCount = $(".gradeOption[value!='']").length;

    var questionAmount = selectedCount; // count how many fields were filled

    }  // <--- what is this??  Prematurely closes 'submitHandler' function

    smoke.confirm('you are about to submit '+questionAmount+' grades - please confirm.',function(e){
        if (e){
            $("#enroller").submit();
            //tried also: $(form).submit();
         }else{
            smoke.alert('save was cancelled', {ok:"close"});
         }
     }, {ok:"yes - save", cancel:"cancel"});

} //submitHandler
```

---

**EDIT:**

Their documentation is very sparse but my guess is that the `smoke.js` JavaScript plugin simply cannot handle any jQuery within its function.

In place of `$(form).submit()`, try the plain JavaScript version:

```
document.getElementById("enroller").submit();
```

Comment: thanks sparky.  yes, i have an `action` in the form.  the loose `}` must be from when i pasted in. the question is (1) even if i pass the `form` in the `submitHandler` - it does not work, and (2) even if i do with the ID (as above) `$("#enroller").submit();` it does not work (which it does work, without the validation).

Comment: @kneidels:  Again, show the rest of the code. You don't call `validate()` more than once, do you? What about the relevant HTML markup?  Any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: @kneidels, it would be best if you could construct a concise demo of this problem in a jsFiddle.  I tried but the oldest CDN version of Bootstrap I could find is 2.0.4 and I get an error that `smoke` is not defined.  In other words, if you want help, please take the time to construct the demo yourself.  With a working demo, we can see where it's breaking.

Comment: got it. will be back shortly

Comment: @kneidels, no wonder nothing happens.  There is no jQuery Validation at all because jQuery itself is not loading... if you'd look at the error console, you'd see a 404 error on `jquery.min.js`.  But that causes the form to always submit... the opposite of your problem description.

Comment: sorry - my bad. forgot to upload it, pls try again

Comment: @kneidels, a jsFiddle is best because it allows me to edit it.  I can't do too much by just looking at your page... _"yep, I see what you mean..."_

Comment: @kneidels, I am suspect about how this `smoke` plugin is working and what it's doing.  `.submit()` is pretty straightforward.  Their docs suck, but my guess is that you simply cannot put jQuery selectors inside of the `smoke` function.  In place of `$(form).submit();` try the plain JavaScript version: `document.getElementById("enroller").submit();`.

Comment: that did the trick!! The wird thing is that the `.submit()` worked fine, even within the `smoke` function - until i hooked up the validation plugin. so i guess there is some clash there.  Thanks for all!  If you can edit your answer I'll check it off.

Comment: @kneidels, why is that weird?  `.submit()` is just JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: i meant that this worked within the smoke function `$("#enroller").submit();`   (before o hooked up the validation)

Comment: @kneidels,  I'm not sure.  Again, the `smoke.js` docs are lacking in this regard.  Perhaps to satisfy your curiosity, you might ask the developer over on his Github forum.